# iOS Partial Keyboard Display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to display only the part of the keyboard in iOS 7?  For example, I would like to display the keyboard, but I do not want the space bar visible.  How would I add the keyboard to display the portion of the keyboard above the space bar?

Comment: No, it is not possible to change the frame of the keyboard.

Comment: create your own keyboard it's easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research has confirmed that it is not possible to adjust the frame of the keyboard.